# tflite_flutter_helper gives issure in deployment

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, gradle, tflite

I am trying to deploy my image classification app to Android and I need to build the app bundle.
I know tflite_flutter_helper is outdated but I don't know what to use to replace it.

I run `flutter build appbundle`
However I get the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
project ':tflite_flutter_helper' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                           2,278ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, tflite_flutter_helper is depreciated. The main usage of the helper package was to decode the image into a byte buffer in the shape that your tflite model required. You can do this with a simple function. But you need to know the input-output shapes of your model. You can use the following function to convert your image to a byte buffer as required by the tflite. Mean and std should be kept at 127.5 for color images. inputSize is the image with and height.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
Future<Uint8List> _imageToByteListFloat32(
      img.Image image, int inputSize, double mean, double std) async {
    var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * inputSize * inputSize * 3);
    var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
    int pixelIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < inputSize; j++) {
        var pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (pixel.r - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (pixel.g - mean) / std;
        buffer[pixelIndex++] = (pixel.b - mean) / std;
      }
    }

    return convertedBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your project's build.gradle and Upgrade kotlin version

```
   // replace with a new version 
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'.
```

Then after Re-Sync Gradle files.